# Is it possible to run a couple of nodes on the same computer in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum

I try to create a local private testnet network of ethereum. It seems like when I run two nodes on the same computer(without vm), it uses the same port and ip address although I set different port for each one of them. Is it possible to run a couple of nodes on the same computer, or should I use a vm for that?
It also showed me that one of the nodes has 8 peers although I set only 2 nodes. how is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are the mandatory options for your node but for the networking only, you can set the port with the following option

```
  --port value          Network listening port (default: 30303)
```

If you are connected to 8 peers but you only have 2, I think you are running your geth on a public networkid

```
--networkid value Network identifier (integer, 1=Frontier, 2=Morden (disused), 3=Ropsten, 4=Rinkeby) (default: 1)
```

You can find all the available options on [this page](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options)

Comment: I see, so the public network is on port 30303? as a network identifier should I choose Ropsten?

Comment: If you want to have a private network (only with your nodes), you have to choose something upper than that, this article can help you a lot https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html